# Does twitter moments appear as a feed?

Tags: twitter

Can users subscribe to it and be abreast with updated tweets? Or is it only a slideshow of the creator's tweets that he/she wants to showcase? What is the best metaphor or analogy for the same? I am looking for a solution where I can publish my thoughts about a certain topic on twitter if possible. Today I think the only alternative is to own a dedicated account. Just looking out for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Moments are generally used for breaking news or some live events like sports. You could create a [collection](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/advanced-tweetdeck-features) on [tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/). They are used for organizing tweets by topics and interests. They also look and feel like normal timelines.

Here's a sample collection from The New York Times on [Hurricane Maria and Puerto Rico](https://twitter.com/nytimes/timelines/912716443820621830)

[image]